# Serializing an empty class (with no field)

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following class:

```
class Foo {
    @JsonCreator
    public Foo() 
    {
    }
}
```

And I get the following exception:

> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No serializer found for class Foo and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) )

It cannot be serialized in this way. And I don't want to ignore the value, I just want to see `{}` output as JSON.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to disable `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` option. See below example:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.disable(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(new Foo()));
```

Above program prints:

```
{}
```

See also:

1. [Serialization features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Serialization-Features).
2. [Deserialization Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Deserialization-Features).
3. [Mapper Features](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/wiki/Mapper-Features).

Answer (score 1):

in this case I would use the **@JsonSerialize** annotation:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonSerialize;

@JsonSerialize
public class Foo {
  public Foo() {}
}
```

Note you will need add this dependency, for maven:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```