# Send empty JSON objet to API

Tags: java, web-services, jackson, jersey

For lab purpose I have to send a JSON object containing others objects and one of them has no property (empty) as you can see :

```
{
     "id": "00u12e3knx76B4PNS4x7",
     "scope": "USER",
     "credentials": {
     "userName": "some@email.com"
     },
     "profile": {}
}
```

I'm using Java Jersey and POJO to generate Java classes from JSON payloads but I cannot find what to send in this case match my API requirement.

Here is my code sample :

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response eventHook(String body, @HeaderParam("Pass") String password) {
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    RequestPayload requestPayload = new RequestPayload();

    writeLogger(body);

    try {
        requestPayload = objectMapper.readValue(body, RequestPayload.class);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    EventsItem event = requestPayload.getData().getEvents().get(0);

    TargetItem targetItem = event.getTarget().get(2);

    RequestApiAssignUser user = new RequestApiAssignUser();

    Credentials credentials = new Credentials();
    credentials.setUserName("id");
    user.setId(getUser.getId());
    user.setScope("USER");
    user.setCredentials(credentials);

    Profile profile = new Profile();
    user.setProfile(profile);

    Response postResponse = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            .target(API_URL)
            .path("apps/" + getApps("0oa13t5dqnkYGDZEd4x7") + "/users")
            .request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .header(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "SSWS " + API_TOKEN)
            .post(Entity.entity(user, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));

    String responseAPI = postResponse.readEntity(String.class);

    return Response.status(200).entity(responseAPI).build();
```

Here is the error due to the imposssibility to serialize Profile Object because it has no properties :

> jakarta.ws.rs.ProcessingException:
> com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
> serializer found for class
> Payload.Api.Apps.Post.Assign.Request.Profile and no properties
> discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable
> SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain:
> Payload.Api.Apps.Post.Assign.Request.RequestApiAssignUser["profile"])

Thanks !

Comment: Can you also add the code of Profile class ?

Comment: It's empty, `public class Profile {}`

Comment: Can you see whether the solutions given here helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25720509/serializing-an-empty-class-with-no-field

Comment: Doesn't work `user.setProfile(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Profile()));
` requires a Object not a String

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you to disable the `SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS` property on the `ObjectMapper`. Normally to configure the `ObjectMapper` with Jersey, you would implement a `ContextResolver`. The the Jackson `ObjectMapper` that's used under the hood would look this resolver up and configure the property.

But in this case, you already are using a mapper in your code. So I would just configure that mapper and then serialize the `User` object into a String and use that JSON string as the entity

```java
objectMapper.disable(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
```

Then at the bottom before your client code just serialize the `User` to a string.

```java
String userJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);
Response postResponse = ClientBuilder.newClient()
            ...
            .post(Entity.entity(userJson, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

In other cases, if you did not already have an `ObjectMapper`, you would implement a `ContextResolver` as I mentioned above.

```java
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public ObjectMapperResolver() {
        mapper.disable(SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS);
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then you would register this with the client

```java
Response postResponse = ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .register(ObjectMapperResolver.class)
        ...
```

Comment: I've added these lines  ```user.setProfile(new Profile());``` and `String userJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(user);`
I'm sending this value to my API `{"profile":{},"credentials":"userName":"jeremie@lyvoc.com"},"scope":"USER","id":"00u12e3knx76B4PNS4x7"}`which seems to be alright, but I'm getting an error from it saying that the body of the request isn't right

Comment: Nethermind, I didn't correctly rebuilt my code, your solution juste worked fine, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You created **Credentials()** object and this is a empty object but you setted userName, now is not empty. Credentials object have a userName variable. But your created **Profile()** object is empty. And you did not set any variable to this **Profile()** object. You setted **Profile()** object to empty **Profile()** object. You need set a real variable.

Comment: No I can't set any variable to Profile object

Comment: How can you set Credentials object to userName? You need getter and setter methods for Profile like Credentials.

Comment: I do not understand your issue with that, my credential object has one String property  "userName" which is an ID.
My profile object has no property, therefore cannot have any getter/setter

Comment: You need add getter and setter methods for Profile. If not, your Profile object will be empty. And you need set a variable for Profile. When you add getter and setter methods and set a variable to Profile, you can see all of them at your JSON.

Comment: My `RequestApiAssignUser` has a setter : `public void setProfile(Profile Profile){ this.Profile = Profile;}`
But I cannot make it to send juste a empty object